# Using objects in HashMaps as a Key

Tags: java, hashmap

so I have a small issue that I cant wrap my head around.

I have a need to store a class object as a key in a map and for it to be retrieved later by a newly created object looking against the map. I have a class that implements `Cloneable` and overrides `toString`, `hashCode` and `equals`, but it seems that the object is unique and no matter how I create the object to use as a key to retrieve the value from the map, the new object that should match the key, doesn't.

#### The Object Class:

```java
package com.keneti.tekkit.objects;

import org.bukkit.block.Block;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;

import com.keneti.main.KenetiPrereq;

/** Simple object representing an block by the ID:DATA.
 * 
 * @author Michael Mason */
public class SimpleBlock implements Cloneable {
    protected final int id;
    protected byte data;
    
    /** Creates a new SimpleBlock object with a data value of zero.
     * 
     * @param id The Block ID. */
    public SimpleBlock(int id) {
        this.id = id;
        this.data = 0;
    }
    
    /** Creates a new SimpleBlock object.
     * 
     * @param id The Block ID.
     * @param data The block data to set. */
    public SimpleBlock(int id, byte data) {
        this.id = id;
        this.data = data;
    }
    
    /** Creates a new SimpleBlock object from a {@link Block}.
     * 
     * @param block A bukkit block. */
    public SimpleBlock(Block block) {
        this(block.getTypeId(), block.getData());
    }
    
    /** Creates a new SimpleBlock object from an {@link ItemStack}.
     * 
     * @param itemStack A bukkit ItemStack. */
    public SimpleBlock(ItemStack itemStack) {
        this(itemStack.getTypeId(), itemStack.getData().getData());
    }
    
    /** Gets the ID of this block.
     * 
     * @return The ID of this block. */
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    
    /** Gets the Data for this block.
     * 
     * @return The Data of this block. */
    public byte getData() {
        return data;
    }
    
    /** Sets the Data for this block.
     * 
     * @param data The Data to set for this block. */
    public void setData(byte data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
    
    @Override
    public Object clone() {
        try {
            SimpleBlock s = (SimpleBlock) super.clone();
            return s;
        }
        catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
            KenetiPrereq.journal.fine("CloneNotSupportedException: SimpleBlock " + this.toString());
            throw new Error(e);
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{SimpleBlock:" + this.id + ":" + this.data + "}";
    }
    
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return this.toString().hashCode();
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof SimpleBlock) return (this.id == ((SimpleBlock) obj).id) && (this.data == ((SimpleBlock) obj).data);
        if (obj instanceof ItemStack) return (this.id == ((ItemStack) obj).getTypeId()) && (this.data == ((ItemStack) obj).getData().getData());
        if (obj instanceof Block) return (this.id == ((Block) obj).getTypeId()) && (this.data == ((Block) obj).getData());
        return false;
    }
    
}
```

#### Running Code

```java
// The Map holding the value
private LinkedHashMap<SimpleBlock, LinkedList<Location>> locationsmap;

// I create the SimpleBlock object like this
SimpleBlock sb = new SimpleBlock(758, (byte) 14);

// I add the locations with the SimpleBlock object as the key.
locationsmap.put(sb, locations);
```

#### Later, in another class:

```java
// so after getting the map in a local variable..
LinkedList<Location> locations = locationsMap.get(new SimpleBlock(758, (byte) 14));
```

When I try to get the object using the same creation data, it doesn't see the object in the map (although I see it when stepping the code, its in there for sure)

My question is, how doesn't this currently work?, I'm sure i've done the required steps to make the object equal?

Thank you in advance :D

Comment: You're probably mutating the object (i.e. call one of its setters) after it has been stored in the map. Make your class immutable. The fact that a SimpleBlock can be equal to something other than another SimpleBlock is extremely dubious.

Comment: Also, try to use the sb variable to get it from the HashMap, that way you can verify if that is/isn't the problem.

Comment: @JB Nizet the SimpleBlock can also equal an `ItemStack` and a `Block` for convenience in other methods, you would recommend not doing that?

Comment: @Zachery I see what I did there, the last line is in another class entirely with no access to the sb variable. I'll make some quick edits. Thanks.

Comment: As explained by Chii's answer, that will break the contract of equals() unless an equal ItemStack and an equal Block also have the same hashCode. It also breaks the contract of equals() if simpleBlock.equals(otherObject) is true, but otherObject.equals(simpleBlock) is false.

Comment: @JBNizet Ahh I see, but when checking for equality of an `ItemStack` to a `SimpleBlock`, I do so by the `int` and `byte` values of an `ItemStack` and not a direct comparison of the `ItemStack` object, still head banging my desk lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation of equals and hashcode does not satisfy the contract required (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29).

In a nutshell, the SimpleBlock object can equal to another object, but have a different hashcode

> If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, then
>   calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce
>   the same integer result.

fix that, and i think you'll fix your problem.

Edit: also, use a library to build the equals and hashcode methods will make it easier: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/EqualsBuilder.html and https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/HashCodeBuilder.html

Comment: Thats awesome, wouldn't the `@Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return this.toString().hashCode();
    }` return the same integer result?

Comment: i dont know what code you're actually running (the example you gave would give you back the correct results so obviously something else is wrong). But i suspect you're not actually using a SimpleBlock when querying, but something else that is supposed to be equal to a SimpleBlock. But because hashes uses the hashcode, the original simpleBlock would've produced a different hashcode that then won't match when you call map.get(notSimpleBlock(758, (byte) 14)). What you should do is fix up the hashcode problem, then investigate. At least it will elmininate a possible source of errors.

Comment: That's true, and it could be the problem if the OP didn't use a SimpleBlock when putting and getting. But apparently, he is...

Comment: @JBNizet This is where a get all confused, so when I created the sb variable with 758 & 14, and the SimpleBlock override methods test against the id and the data (758 & 14) to determine the equality, those should return true, then the hash is based off the toString override that should also match?

Comment: @Chii Thank you for those links, I shall test and see what i come up with on those.

Comment: @MichaelJohnMason It should, and it will. As I said, my guess is that you have mutated the object after it has been stored in the map.

Comment: @JBNizet I'll step through the whole sequence and see what's going on, Thanks for the help :D

Comment: So after some head scratching, I randomly added 99 to the returned integer of hash code `return this.toString().hashCode() + 99;` and I have no idea why it works, but it works. Could anyone shed some light on why this would make it work?